# Save browser PDF to disk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa). I would like to generate html to PDF and save the PDF to disk. I've been following the code sample that was provided by [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/blob/master/Rotativa.Demo/Controllers/HomeController.cs) but got stuck where the PDF showing on the browser. I believe the following line shows it to the browser

```
return File(binary, "application/pdf");
```

I would like to save it to the disk path `D:\PDFs`

```
var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Giorgio" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf", };
var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);
return File(binary, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: You can not save a file directly to disk. Unless you are using some browser extension combine with nativemessaging

Answer (score 0):

To force it download and not show on browser, append this extra header

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
```